# NoReverseMatch at /polls/top/ 'polls' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django

Parent app name is mysite,child app name is polls.
I wrote in views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Polls
def top(request):
    data = Polls.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    return render(request,'index.html',{'data':data})

def detail(request):
    data = Polls.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    return render(request,'detail.html',{'data':data})
```

in child app's urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    url('top/', views.top, name='top'),
    url('detail/<int:pk>/', views.top,name='detail'),
]
```

in parent app's urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url,include

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]
```

in index.html

```
<main>
            {% for item in data %}
                            <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
                            <a href="{% url 'polls:detail' item.pk %}">SHOW DETAIL
</a>

            {% endfor %}
</main>
```

When I access top method, NoReverseMatch at /polls/top/
'polls' is not a registered namespace error happens.I am using Django 2.0,so I think namespace cannot used.I wrote app_name ,so I really cannot understand why this error happens.How should I fix this?What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

The var `app_name` should be inside `polls.urls` not in the urls.py parent's file. Also if you want to use the new routing that Django provides remember add the `path` module:

```
from django.urls import path
path('detail/<int:pk>/', views.top,name='detail'),
```

If you're using the `url` module check this and be careful with what version you're using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/